# Big Oh, discrete- mathematics trouble writing out problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to study for a CS test that involves Big Oh.  The question is if you have a function that runs at O(n^2) and at input 1000 it takes 15 seconds to run.  At 60 seconds what would n be.  2000,4000,6000, none of the above.  I believe it is none of the above and that an extra 1000 added to n would take longer than 60 seconds which would rule out the three answers but I am having trouble logically writing this out to see the math.  I was hoping someone could help me understand the exact math of this.

Here is the real question from the practice exam I copied.  I might have worded it wrong above

An algorithm takes 15 seconds to solve a problem of size 1000. If the
algorithm is quadratic – i.e., runs as O(N^2), how large a problem can be solved
in 60 seconds?
(a) 2000
(b) 4000
(c) 6000
(d) none of the above

Comment: Frankly, that's a terrible question (not from you, from the exam.) There is no way to tell given the information what $n$ is, but "none of the above" seems wrong, too, in that it could be any of the above. This is because $O(n^2)$ is just an upper bound.

Comment: I copied over the question word for word.  Does that help?  I could have worded it wrong trying to explain it myself

Comment: My guess is the question should have said $\Omega(n)$, but even then, it’s  a crummy question. Perhaps it’s an attempt to test whether you know what “quadratic” means in the most uncomplicated sense, that the algorithm takes  time $kN^2$ for an input of size $N$, where $k$ is some constant. If so, then when the algorithm takes four times as long to run ($60$ seconds vs. $15$), the input must have been twice as large, because $k(2N)^2=4(kN^2)$, so $2000$ would be the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think you got it.  thanks for writing it out